# How to html text show as par this attribute in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attr

The problem is not shown in each tag. I face some issues like this: `attr is not a function`.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  jQuery('.custom-size .size .text').each(function() {
    var option_label = this.attr("option-label");
    jQuery(this).text(option_label);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="custom-size">
  <div class="size">
    <div class="text" option-label="NONE"></div>
    <div class="text" option-label="44">NONE</div>
    <div class="text" option-label="46">44</div>
    <div class="text" option-label="48">46</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `jQuery(this).attr` - since `this` will be an actual element, not a jquery object

Comment: I think you should read into data attributes. Instead of inventing a custom attribute and trying to read out the value of the custom attribute, you could have used a data-attribute in the first place

Comment: jQuery(this.attr("option-label")); some issue

Comment: read the comment of Jaromanda X carefully and correctly. His solution works perfectly. You setting the round brackets wrong.

Comment: try this => jQuery(this).attr("option-label");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Since you are using the latest version of jQuery use `$` instead of `jQuery`

b) You need to use `$(this)` instead of `this`.

c) Better to use data-attributes.

Working sample:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.custom-size .size .text').each(function() {
    var option_label = $(this).data("option-label");
    $(this).text(option_label);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="custom-size">
  <div class="size">
    <div class="text" data-option-label="NONE"></div>
    <div class="text" data-option-label="44">NONE</div>
    <div class="text" data-option-label="46">44</div>
    <div class="text" data-option-label="48">46</div>
  </div>
</div>
```